# DataFlowRunner + Beam in streaming mode with a SideInput AsDict hangs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simple graph that reads from a pubsub message (currently just a single string key), creates a very short window, generates 3 integers that use this key via a `beam.ParDo`, and a simple Map that creates a single "config" with this as a key.

Ultimately, there are 2 PCollections:

- items: `[('key', 0), ('key', 1), ...]`
- infos: `[('key', 'the value is key')]`

I want a final `beam.Map` over `items` that uses `infos` as a dictionary side input so I can look up the value in the dictionary.

Using the LocalRunner, the final print works with the side input.
On DataFlow the first two steps print, but the final Map with the side input never is called, presumably because it somehow is an unbounded window (despite the earlier window function).

I am using runner_v2, dataflow prime, and streaming engine.

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
pubsub_message = (
    p | beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(
        subscription='projects/myproject/testsubscription') |
    'SourceWindow' >> beam.WindowInto(
        beam.transforms.window.FixedWindows(1e-6),
        trigger=beam.transforms.trigger.Repeatedly(beam.transforms.trigger.AfterCount(1)),
        accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING))

def _create_items(pubsub_key: bytes) -> Iterable[tuple[str, int]]:
  for i in range(3):
    yield pubsub_key.decode(), i

def _create_info(pubsub_key: bytes) -> tuple[str, str]:
  return pubsub_key.decode(), f'the value is {pubsub_key.decode()}'

items = pubsub_message | 'CreateItems' >> beam.ParDo(_create_items) | beam.Reshuffle()
info = pubsub_message | 'CreateInfo' >> beam.Map(_create_info)

def _print_item(keyed_item: tuple[str, int], info_dict: dict[str, str]) -> None:
  key, _ = keyed_item
  log(key + '::' + info_dict[key])

_ = items | 'MapWithSideInput' >> beam.Map(_print_item, info_dict=beam.pvalue.AsDict(info))
```

Here is the output in local runner:

```
Creating item 0
Creating item 1
Creating item 2
Creating info b'key'
key::the value is key
key::the value is key
key::the value is key
```

Here is the DataFlow graph:

[image: DataFlow Graph]

I've tried various windowing functions over the AsDict, but I can never get it to be exactly the same window as my input.

Thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: The input of `beam.pvalue.AsDict` has to be a tuple of key-value pairs, with unique keys. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74503969/16622985).