# I want to pass side input AsDIct but getting error "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 101; 2 is required"

Tags: python, apache-beam

```
class load_side_input(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self,pubsub_message):  
        message = pubsub_message.decode("utf8")
        
        output:typing.Dict={}
        for key in message.keys():
          output[key] = self.tag_model[key]
        return [output]
```

```
side_input = (p
                | "AMM Events" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=opts.ammSub)
                | "Trigger event" >> beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows(), trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1)),
                                                  accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
                | "Parse and Update Cache" >> beam.ParDo(load_side_input())
               
                )
```

```
enrichment = (rows
              | 'Data Validation and Enrichment' >> beam.ParDo(validation(),y_side=AsDict(side_input))
      )
```

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 434, in __getitem__
    self._cache[target_window] = self._side_input_data.view_fn(raw_view)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 101; 2 is required [while running 'Data Enrichment-ptransform-128']
```

Answer (score 3):

You feed the function `beam.pvalue.AsDict` the incorrect input format. According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.pvalue.html#apache_beam.pvalue.AsDict):

> Parameters:   pcoll – Input pcollection. **All elements should be key-value pairs (i.e. 2-tuples) with unique keys**.

Here is a minimum working example, which can be run at [Apache Play](https://play.beam.apache.org/)

```
import apache_beam as beam

def use_side_input(main, side_input):
   return side_input[main]


class BadSideInputCreator(beam.DoFn):
   def process(self, element):
     output = {}
     output['1'] = 'value1'
     output['2'] = 'value2'
     yield [output]  # this is a list of an dict and not a 2-tuple
 
class GoodSideInputCreator(beam.DoFn):
   def process(self, element):
     output = {}
     output['1'] = 'value1'
     output['2'] = 'value2'
     for key, value in output.items():
        yield (key, value)  # this is a 2-tuple

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  main = (
    pipeline
    | "init main" >> beam.Create(['1', '2'])
  )
  
  side = (
    pipeline
    | "init side" >> beam.Create(['dummy'])
    | beam.ParDo(BadSideInputCreator())  # replace with GoodSideInputCreator
  )

  (
    main
    | "use side input" >> beam.Map(use_side_input, side_input=beam.pvalue.AsDict(side))
    | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Running with `BadSideInputCreator` throws your error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

while with `GoodSideInputCreator` we get the expected result

```
value1
value2
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael Ruth, but in that case, I get only the last element as side input, not all elements added using GoodSideInputCreator.

Comment: `class BadSideInputCreator(beam.DoFn):
   def process(self, element):
     
     return [('1','value1'),('2','value2')]` this function return similar output to GoodSideInputCreator and both functions work well and gives a required output when run with direct runner but when I run with Dataflow runner it gives only last element (tuple) as side input.

Comment: I do not know how the rest of your pipeline looks like, but it is possible you need to add [windows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) in order to get the main and side input together